SUM on google sheet always returns 0
The sum on my spreadsheet column Category always returns 0. 
I have formatted column Amount as Number but still it doesn't work. I had also removed all currency symbols from that column using find & replace. What do I have to change?
It works flawlessly on MS Excel but not here.

You file Locale is UNITED KINGDOM and UK use dot . as decimal separator. So, google sheet treating comma , as string and your full column treating as string instead of number value. Either change Locale or change decimal separator. You can try the following formula by not changing anything in google-sheet.
=SUM(INDEX(--SUBSTITUTE(C4:C5,",",".")))



Thank you harun, I simply changed the locale and it worked.

In your cells are stored as text rather than numbers, the formula will ignore them.  This often happens when the numbers use a comma (,) as the decimal separator instead of a period (.).
Solution:
You can select the cells in the range  and change the format to "Number/Currency" using your spreadsheet software's formatting options.

I formatted columns C and D as euro currency. The result is still the same. Please have a link at the spreadsheet.

Try this
The first answer's explanation is correct, though the solution provided is incorrect. You can use a formula to process the range and sum it.
Formula
=REDUCE(0,C2:C, LAMBDA(a,c, a+REGEXREPLACE(c,"[,]",".")))

